# How to create an array of functions in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, function, for-loop

I have the following code, it works great but I want to reduce the for loop statement like to create an array function the only one for loop use for all statement. here is the code I have:

```
string Combine1 = "", result1 = "";
TextBox[] StoreGame1 = new TextBox[5] {
    txtGameOne1, txtGameOne2, txtGameOne3, txtGameOne4, txtGameOne5
};
string Combine2 = "", result2 = "";
TextBox[] StoreGame2 = new TextBox[5] {
    txtGameTwo1, txtGameTwo2, txtGameTwo3, txtGameTwo4, txtGameTwo5
};
string Combine3 = "", result3 = "";
TextBox[] StoreGame3 = new TextBox[5] {
    txtGameThree1, txtGameThree2, txtGameThree3, txtGameThree4, txtGameThree5
};
if (
StoreGame1[0].Text != "" && StoreGame1[1].Text != "" && StoreGame1[2].Text != "" && StoreGame1[3].Text != "" && StoreGame1[4].Text != "" && StoreGame2[0].Text != "" && StoreGame2[1].Text != "" && StoreGame2[2].Text != "" && StoreGame2[3].Text != "" && StoreGame2[4].Text != "" && StoreGame3[0].Text != "" && StoreGame3[1].Text != "" && StoreGame3[2].Text != "" && StoreGame3[3].Text != "" && StoreGame3[4].Text != "") {
    // For Game 1
    for (int i = 0; i < StoreGame1.Length; i++) {
        Combine1 += StoreGame1[i].Text + "-";
    }
    result1 = Combine1.Substring(0, Combine1.Length - 1);

    // For Game 2

    for (int i = 0; i < StoreGame2.Length; i++) {
        Combine2 += StoreGame2[i].Text + "-";
    }
    result2 = Combine2.Substring(0, Combine2.Length - 1);

    // For Game 3

    for (int i = 0; i < StoreGame3.Length; i++) {
        Combine3 += StoreGame3[i].Text + "-";
    }
    result3 = Combine3.Substring(0, Combine3.Length - 1);

    if (txtBuyNumber.Text != "") {
        long mobilenumber = long.Parse(txtBuyNumber.Text);
        string submit = client.SubmitBuying("", 1, 1, result1 + ";" + result2 + ";" + result3, countgame, 1, "PC", mobilenumber, "Office");
        if (submit == "06") {
            MessageBox.Show("Bet Success!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("System error please try again", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter select any customer phone number first!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Any game still empty please enter animal number before buy", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    focusedTextbox.Focus();
}
```

It works, but how can I implement this using any function to reduce the for loop.

Thanks,

**Edit:**
I tried create a function

```
private string DelimeterGameTypeOne(TextBox[] ArrValue)
    {
        string com = "", res = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < ArrValue.Length; i++)
        {
            com += ArrValue[i].Text + "-";
        }
        return res = com.Substring(0, com.Length - 1);
    }
```

and Called it like

```
// For Game 1
result1 = DelimeterGameTypeOne(StoreGame1);
// For Game 2
result2 = DelimeterGameTypeOne(StoreGame2);
// For Game 3
result3 = DelimeterGameTypeOne(StoreGame3);
```

And now I get it works.
Thank you everyone for supporting.

Comment: Create a function and accept 'StoreGame' as input and perform your logic, return the resultant string. You can invoke this function instead of writing for loop every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your `for` loops could be expressed like this instead:

```
// For Game 1
result1 = string.Join("-", StoreGame1.Select(item => item.Text));
// For Game 2
result2 = string.Join("-", StoreGame2.Select(item => item.Text));
// For Game 3
result3 = string.Join("-", StoreGame3.Select(item => item.Text));
```

Wouldn't that work just as well for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pre-defined generic *delegates* Func<> and Action<> like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Func<int,bool> [] funcArray = new Func<int,bool> [] () {
    Func1
   ,Func2
   ,(i) => (i >= 36) 
};

bool Func1 (int i) { return i <= 16; }
bool Func2 (int I) { return I >= 25; }
```